# Criar SplashScreen para mostrar progresso de cópia de arquivo

Tags: java, javafx

Estou tentando criar uma `splashscreen` pois quando minha aplicação é aberta eu realizo algumas ações demoradas, como:

- Copiar arquivos
- Executar um .exe

Minha `Main` está assim:

```
import com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class Main 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      LauncherImpl.launchApplication(MyApplication.class, SplashScreenLoader.class, args);
   }
}
```

A classe `MyApplication` chama minha tela inicial do programa e a classe `SplashScreenLoader` seria a responsável por ser minha `splash` está assim:

```
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Preloader;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SplashScreenLoader extends Preloader {

    private Stage splashScreen;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        URL arquivo = getClass().getResource("SplashScreen.fxml");
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(arquivo);
        splashScreen = stage;
        splashScreen.setTitle("Iniciando..");
        splashScreen.setScene(new Scene(parent));
        splashScreen.setResizable(false);
        splashScreen.show();
        splashScreen.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void handleApplicationNotification(PreloaderNotification notification) {
        if (notification instanceof StateChangeNotification) {
            splashScreen.hide();
        }
    }

}
```

O `controller` do meu `fxml`, seu método `initialize` é responsável por realizar a cópia de meus arquivos, ele possui o seguinte trecho de código:

```
try
{
    this.lblTitle.setText(Confg.project);
    if(this.verifyArchives(Confg.origin, "php", Confg.pathPHP))
    {
        boolean start = false;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                this.runPHP(Confg.localhost);
                start = true;
            } catch (Exception e) { }
        }while(!start);
        this.verifyArchives(Confg.pathWWW + Confg.project, "www", Confg.pathWWW + Confg.project);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) { this.lblStatus.setText(e.getMessage()); }
```

O método `verifyArchives` é responsável por verificar se os arquivos já existem, e caso não existe é chamado o método `copyAll`, passando parâmetros como a origem e destino, e o `label` da minha `SplashScreen` que será responsável por exibir o status do processo.

```
public static boolean copyAll(File origin, File destiny, boolean overwrite, Label info) throws IOException, UnsupportedOperationException
{
    if (!destiny.exists())
        destiny.mkdir();

    if (!origin.isDirectory())
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Origem deve ser um diretório");

    if (!destiny.isDirectory())
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Destino deve ser um diretório");

    File[] files = origin.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i)
    {
        if (files[i].isDirectory())
            copyAll(files[i], new File(destiny + "\\" + files[i].getName()), overwrite, info);
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Copiando arquivo: " + files[i].getName());
            info.setText("Copiando arquivo: " + files[i].getName());
            copy(files[i], new File(destiny + "\\" + files[i].getName()), overwrite);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

No fim do método eu tenho um `println` e um `setText` que deveria transformar o texto do meu label no status atual do processo. Mas ao iniciar o programa pela primeira vez (que é quando ele irá copiar os arquivos), as mensagens do `println` são exibidas no console, por exemplo: "*Copiando arquivo: blablabla.txt*". E só após copiar todos os arquivos que minha `splash` é aberta, com o `label` com a mensagem "*Copiando arquivo: ultimo-arquivo.txt*".

A dúvida é exatamente essa, como eu exibo a `splashscreen` um pouco antes de executar a cópia dos arquivos, para que possa ver visto o processo de cópia na minha splash?

Comment: Se você criar uma interface para notificar o status não funciona? Um listener ?

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas acho que não.

Comment: Na tela em si eu estava tentando fazer algo pra atrasar a copia dos arquivos, como um sleep ou um wait, o this.wait() funcionou mas mesmo colocando um tempo para ele esperar ele ficou pausado, sem chamar o método de copiar arquivo.

Comment: "*O `controller` do meu `fxml` enfim, no seu método `initialize` é responsável por realizar a cópia de meus arquivos*". - Você poderia postar mais sobre o seu `controller` e sobre o seu `fxml`? Estou quase certo que é nisso que está o problema.

Comment: Creio que o problema não está no `fxml`, ele é só um `panel` com um `webview` dentro, com o `controller` definido corretamente. E o da splash é um panel com dois label apenas. Já o controller tem apenas as declarações dos o objetos de tela(web view no caso da minha pagina inicial, e os labels no caso da minha splash). E ambos teem somente o metodo initialize, que na splash tenta chamar os métodos de copia de arquivo e o da pagina inicial apenas carrega um link no meu webview, o metodo runPHP não é importante. Acho que o problema está no verifyArchuve ou CopyAll

Comment: Eles estão sendo executados antes da tela se abrir, e deveriam ser executados após a abertura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei dizer se o seu `PreLoader` está configurado corretamente, principalmente por causa disso:

```
import com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl;
```

Normalmente, se usa o `launch` da própria `Application`.

Agora, o recomendado para executar tarefas longas, é criar um método que execute em uma thread, e avise o `PreLoader` quando tudo estiver certo, algo como:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    Stage stage;
    BooleanProperty ready = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    private void chamadaDemorada() {
        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                //por exemplo, a sua função que copia arquivos
                copyAll(origin, destiny, overwrite, info);
                // se quiser enviar o progresso                         
                notifyPreloader(new ProgressNotification(progresso));
                //e quando estiver pronto
                ready.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);
                notifyPreloader(new StateChangeNotification(
                    StateChangeNotification.Type.BEFORE_START));
                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        chamadaDemorada();

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLdaApp.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        ready.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            public void changed(
                ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(t1)) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            stage.show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

sendo que esse método deve ser chamado do método `start` da `Application`.

Caso queira tentar outros métodos, sugiro verificar o documento sobre [PreLoaders](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm) (em inglês).

Comment: Só não consegui entender o `ProgressNotification`

Comment: Usar `ProgressNotification` do jeito que eu mostrei ali, não faz sentido. Deixei apenas como uma referência do que você pode fazer. O certo seria chamar `notifyPreloader(new ProgressNotification(progresso));` dentro do seu método que copia arquivos. A cada etapa completa, executando esta notificação.